# How to organize a core spring boot project and a project that wraps it

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture

I am currently developing a Spring Boot web application.

A series of endpoints handling core functionalities, such as file uploads and code management, have been aggregated to form a core Spring Boot project. This project was packaged as a FAT-JAR, including all dependencies, to facilitate its use. Other Spring Boot projects have attempted to implement business logic through extension and inheritance.

This configuration is necessary to separate core functionalities from business logic. It allows the core to provide basic functionalities, while new or modified business functionalities can be developed by extending or inheriting the core functionalities, thus aiming to improve maintenance efficiency. Moreover, the core project was packaged as a JAR to prevent source modifications and to avoid errors due to unnecessary changes by those developing the business logic.

When the Spring Boot project was compressed into a JAR and included in another project, it was confirmed that all instances could be created and executed on a single embedded Tomcat. However, this structure proved problematic when encountering issues, such as when using other libraries with dependencies, making it difficult to find references and solutions. Consequently, we are exploring alternative structures that satisfy the aforementioned conditions.

More specifically, for instance, the Spring Security configurations defined in the Spring Boot project packaged as a JAR did not take effect as intended in other projects that included the JAR file of this project.

In conclusion, I believe the current structure has several issues. In this context, what kind of architecture do you think would be more suitable?

I would appreciate multiple perspectives and insights on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Jars that are used as dependencies shouldn't be spring boot jars. Spring Boot jars have a specific structure which don't make it suitable to be used as dependencies. Seperate the shared parts into regular jars and use those as dependencies **not** the spring boot packaged jar.

Comment: @M.Deinum 

Thank you for your opinion.

If so, in the above situation, which one would you recommend, including the spring boot multi-module or the regular JAR form you mentioned?

Comment: It is not an opinion it is the recommended way due to the nature of the spring boot jars. Put the general / shared stuff in a regular jar (which doesn't mean you cannot use Spring Boot features, just don't package it as a spring boot jar). In that jar/project/module you could even put auto configuration to automatically set things up. That is the recommended way.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand exactly. Thank you for your response.